# Plot the results of counting values with Seaborn

Tags: seaborn

I have a dataframe of medical data with a Class column that represents the outcome of a type of cancer. The value 2 is for benign and the value 4 is for malign. So far my code is the following:

```
b,m=df["Class"].value_counts()
```

so when I print both values I got:

```
b= 450 m= 250
```

and I want to display those values on a barplot using seaborn, so I made the following:

```
sns.countplot(data=df["Class"].value_counts(),x=["benign","malign"])
```

The problem is that it prints only one value like this:

[image]

What am I missing? Also the scale of count only displays from 0.0 to 1.0 and I would like to display the real values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sns.countplot, you don't need to manually calculate the various types of counts inside df['class']. Since there is no dataset you use, here's a demo:

```
import seaborn as sns

titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
ax = sns.countplot(x="class", data=titanic)
```

[image: demo]

In summary, you only need to provide data and x for sns.countplot to achieve your desired effect. In your example, it may be like this:

```
sns.countplot(x="Class", data=df)
```

good luck!

Comment: @Little Passenger's class(1, 2, 3) of "titanic" demo here corresponds to the "benign"/"malign" in your df["Class"]. Seaborn is different from matplotlib and does not need to manually count the input of the bar graph.